# Flexslider stops displaying in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, carousel, flexslider

I'm currently using Flexslider 2.1, and Safari 5.1.7 using Flexslider as a Carousel with thumbnails and slides.

I have 58 images in my slideshow and it works well in all browsers except Safari.
The slideshow gets to image #38 and then displays just half of the image (the other half is there, but invisible). After that the rest of the images do not display at all. They are there, and I can right click on the empty space and save the image to the desktop. It will just not display.

I am using `OnLoad`.

It does it whether I am on localhost or an online server.

The total size of the image folder is 4 MB.

Does Safari have some sort of restriction?

I have looked high and low in the forum, I did find something about half an image displaying, and to revert back to 2.0, but that does not do it.

Update:

The slides and thumbnails were set to animation: "slide"

Changing the animation type for the slides to 'fade' all the images display as they should, Changing the animation type for the slides back to 'slide' and the problem occurs again.

I had also tried compressing the images smaller, made no difference, and re-arranging the order of the images, made no difference, the 38th image was still cut in half and none from there on would display.